# how does gitlab prevent ssh as user git

Tags: git, ssh

I installed gitlab http://gitlab.com/ on my server and I can't understand one thing.

General recommendation for every git server is that user `git` doesn't have a valid shell and instead of /bin/bash a git-shell is used. This however must not be set for gitlab to work and /bin/bash is required as a login shell instead.

For this reason I was afraid that users could ssh to server using the keys they upload using gitlab, but it seems that it uses some **magic** that actually prevents user to login directly:

```
petanb@debian:~$ ssh git@remus
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Welcome to GitLab, petr.bena!
Connection to remus closed.
```

I checked whole folder of git user in /home/git, `.profile` `.bashrc` and content of `.ssh` is all OK, so how does it do that? How does it prevent users from ssh? What kind of ssh hook is that?

Answer (score 1):

This is very probably because, on remus server, git user's .ssh/authorized_keys file sets the option **no-pty** before your SSH public key. For example:

> no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,**no-pty**
>   ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAA..... user@machine